# ./install_bam.sh and i get an error stating "cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, putty, binary-files

I am trying to install a software through PuTTY. When I try to execute the `chmod +x ./install_bam.sh` command  to obtain the permission to run the `./install_bam.sh` and I get an error stating

> cannot execute binary file

The permissions on the file are fine. I tried doing it as `root` also, but just can’t get it to work.

Any clues, ideas?

Comment: What's the first line of the file say?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command:

```
# mount
```

You might have a `noexec` parameter in effect on the filesystem.

Remove the parameters `noexec`, and remount the filesystem.